# Android development FTP Client

Tags: java, android, ftp

I recently made a FTP server which runs fine.
I'm able to connect with this server by browsing with my laptop and my smartphone.
Now I want this same connection to be made by my a self made application in java.
So I downloaded a library from 'commons.apache.org' which contains a class FTPClient which I should be able to use for making a connection.
In my program I made an object of this class and invoked a connect function with an ip and port as it's parameters. Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    {
        TextView textView;
        FTPClient ftpClient;
        String ip = "192.168.1.136";
        int port = 21;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textField_id);
            ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            try{
                this.ftpClient.connect(ip,port);
            }catch(Exception e){
                textView.setText("Failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

The message of the error keeps telling me a 'null' (nullpointerexpception)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Comment: I have the full stacktrace in a string, but it has printed it out to the screen (application is running on my android device). I made a screenshot, but i guess i can't post images. Is there a different way to output the stacktrace?

Comment: Here is the full stacktrace:
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)

Comment: the permissions are set?

Comment: Here is the full stacktrace:                                                                               
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)
 libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84) libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112) java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192) java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460) java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833) org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:182)

Comment: Yes...I have the permission set:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: It's weird, because I've seen different examples doing pretty much the exact same thing.

Comment: what is your minSdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your `onCreate` method

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Although my ftp server doesn't run for some reason, I tried this with a different ftp server and thisn line of code works. So I really want to thank you. And may I ask...What does this line of code do? What does it mean? Gives it permission? I already did that in the XML code, but I guess it should be added to the java class as well.

Comment: I really want to upvote your answer, but I need 15 reputation. Can I like something else?